# What lens is better?

Tags: macro-lenses

Which of the following lenses is better (note: I know very little about cameras):

Nikon 70-300mm f/4-5.6G AF Nikkor SLR Camera Lens

or

Sigma 70-300mm f/4-5.6 SLD DG Macro Lens

Are these lenses good for portraits or action shots?

Comment: The question is tagged as "macro-lenses", but you ask about portraits and action shots, so what is your primary purpose for this lens?

Comment: These previous questions might already cover this - [70-300mm consumer lens for Nikon D5100](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39034/70-300mm-consumer-lens-for-nikon-d5100) and [Which 70-300mm lens between the Nikon VR and Sigma?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/which-70-300mm-lens-between-the-nikon-vr-and-sigma)

Comment: Also [Which 70-300mm f4-5.6 lens is “better?”](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/which-70-300mm-f4-5-6-lens-is-better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lenses are both extremely similar. The Sigma focuses much closer than the Nikon which gives a magnification of 0.5X compared to 0.25X. This lets you fill the frame with a smaller object, roughly half the size with the Sigma.

Note that the Nikkor is lighter and does not have a built-in focus motor, so it will  autofocus only with a mid-to-high-end camera. With entry-level models, currently D3xxx / D5xxx, it still works but only with manual focus.

Image quality is the other differentiation but it has been a while I've seen these lenses. The Sigma is a lower-end offering, so expect it to be of lower image quality. Sigma has improved image quality over the years, but I'd say that model predates this.